# Why do we have neuralnetwork tag rather than neural-network?

Tags: discussion

There are `deep-learning`, `machine-learning`, `data-cleaning` tags, why do we have `neuralnetwork` tag instead of `neural-network`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agree, it should be `neural-network`. Let me see if I have enough power to just change that.